# WPF Label Content: How to avoid reference to Alt Key?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have defined the WPF label with **content="Label_Label"**.
While displaying it shows **"LabelLabel**". The first **"_"** is 
considered for **"Alt Key"** Reference.
In my real requirement I am assigning Content to Label 
dynamically, So please specify solution to this problem.

`<Label Content="Label_Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,42,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88" UseLayoutRounding="False" ClipToBounds="False" />`

Comment: Do you mean you want the label to display "Label_Label" rather than recognizing the "_L" as an access key?

Comment: @Matt: I want to display my Content as it is.  If it is "Label_Label" I want "Label_Label". I want to see the same thing I type. I cant use the double underscore "__" so solve the problem as I am getting the dynamic content and have no right to change it.

Comment: Ok in that case my answer should suit you.

Comment: Why are you using a `Label` if you don't want to use the access key feature? Why not just a `TextBlock` or `ContentControl`?

Comment: @Gabe: Thanks a lot I was not knowing about the existence of ContentControl. I am just one Month old in WPF. TextBlock looks does't suite to my requirement.

Comment: OK, I made my comment an answer if you want to check it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're binding your label's content to some data and can't "escape" the underscore in the data (per mwtb's answer), then the other option is to wrap the text in a TextBlock inside the label. TextBlocks have no concept of an access key so they'll display the text as is.

So instead of this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyText}" />
```

You can do this:

```
<Label><TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" /></Label>
```

Assuming "MyText" contains the string "Hello_World", the former will display HelloWorld while the latter will display Hello_World.

**Update**

Per your comment, here's the same thing in code:

```
var tb = new TextBlock();
tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("MyText"));
var label = new Label
{
    Content = tb
};
```

That's untested but should work. Obviously you'd then have to add "label" to your visual tree in the usual manner.

Comment: Your fix solves my problems exactly as required. 
Can I ask you for more help.

<Label  Name="myLabel">
 <TextBlock Text="MyText"/>
</Label>

Same I want to do using below kind of code.
Label myLabel = new Label()
.....
TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock()
......

Comment: I am accepting your solution As it works for my requirement. If you get chance please look in to my above comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the underscore by using two in a row:

```
Content="Label__Label"
```

I'm not sure what additional question you're implying by "In my real requirement I am assigning Content to Label dynamically"

Comment: I Cant use double underscore "__" to solve the problem as I am getting the dynamic content and have no right to change it.

Comment: The other answer should suit you then.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the only difference between a `Label` and a `ContentControl` is that a `Label` allows use of an access key. If you don't want the access key feature, just use a `ContentControl`.